# RibbonMenuButton with dynamic content

Tags: wpf, binding, ribbon

I try to enter dynamic content to RibbonMenuButton of Microsoft WPF Ribbon in its ItemsSource property,
but the arrow in the RibbonMenuButton disapears when no hardcopy content (like TextBlock line inside the control) exists

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to apply a [DataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.aspx) to your custom object for it to be displayed the way you want